# How to write a login page that handles expired passwords (ZOS/390/CICS)

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-liberty, cics

I know that the j2ee spec doesn't allow for directly handing password expiry and change. See [IBM redbook "WebSphere Application Server on z/OS and Security Integration" at page 57](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4161.pdf) where this is clearly stated.

Has anyone managed to create a login suite that uses extensions to detect expired passwords, and allows them to be changed on some other page? I've tried using the com.ibm.390 suite but this seems to fail CICS authorisation when invoked, possibly because the caller is as yet unauthenticated.

This is a java -> ibm cics question so please could you constrain answers and comments to this sphere rather than Spring etc?

java 1.8, cics 5.3, liberty v17
Its the enquiry mechanism and update mechanism that I need assistance with, I can handle the login suite, filters and servlets myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking at the [CICS API](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=development-cics-command-summaryl) and mapping to [JCICS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=applications-java-development-using-jcics) classes.  You could write COBOL (or PL/I, or Assembler) programs wrapped around those CICS APIs not exposed by the JCICS classes, then `invoke` with a channel or commarea.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to use [com.ibm.os390.security.PlatformUser](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.zsecurity.api.80.doc/com.ibm.os390.security/index.html) in a CICS JVM as it uses __passwd which requires the caller to be program controlled, which is not feasible. If you can call into a CICS program this could issue a [CHANGE PASSWORD](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGMCP_5.4.0/reference/commands-api/dfhp4_changepassword.html) command. You may also be able to create a Liberty [JASPIC](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_develop_jaspic.html) provider to assist in the process.

Comment: thanks phil, I recognise you from redbooks and java samples